# Get index value from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, series

I have a Pandas dataframe (countries) and need to get specific index value. (Say index 2 => I need Japan)

[image: Series]

I used iloc, but i got the data (7.542)

```
return countries.iloc[2]
7.542
```

Comment: you sure it's a series and not a dataframe?

Comment: Maybe the confusion has to do with the fact that each column in a dataframe is a series. @beshr, are you operating on a column (or columns) in a dataframe, or just handling the dataframe directly?

Comment: Downvote. Since the edit queue is full: the header is very vague. You want to get the value from a chosen index of a df. One might read the header as if you search for the index value(s) for a given df value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

call the index directly

```
return countries.index[2]
```

but what you post here looks like a pandas dataframe instead of a series - if that's the case do

```
countries['Country_Name'].iloc[2]
```

Comment: the second solution didn't work on my dataframe, but the first solution did. The second solution works for accessing a value in a column. If you want the index of the value of a column, you would do ```countries['Country_Name'].index[2]```

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly the question I had! Reading the other responses helped me find this answer.

As other answerers have mentioned, the presented structure of the table looks like you have a dataframe with two columns, one column for 'Country_Names' and another unnamed column for values, in which case the index would default to [0, 1 ... n].

But, your sample code `return countries.iloc[2] #7.542` suggests you have a series since it only returns a scalar value, rather than a key:value pair with an index and a datatype (see below).

So, let's assume that you have a dataframe, as you say you do, with one column of values and 'Country_Names' as the index. I'll add a name to the values column and add a second values column:

```
countries = pd.DataFrame({'Country_Names': ['China', 'United States', 'Japan', 'United Kingdom', 'Russian Federation', 'Brazil'],
                          'Values1': [1.5, 10.53, 7.542, 3.487, 6.565, 8.189],
                          'Values2': [1,2,3,4,5,6]}).set_index('Country_Names')
print(countries)

#                     Values1  Values2
# Country_Names                       
# China                 1.500        1
# United States        10.530        2
# Japan                 7.542        3
# United Kingdom        3.487        4
# Russian Federation    6.565        5
# Brazil                8.189        6
```

Incidentally, each column of a dataframe *is* a series, sharing an index with the dataframe to which it belongs. That said, you could have only one column and it would still be a dataframe, though accessing column one would return a series (see below).

Both dataframes and series' have the index attribute in common, as well as other attributes.

```
countries.index[2] #The 3rd index of the dataframe:
# 'Japan'

countries['Values1'].index[2] #The 3rd index of the 1st column (which is a series)
# 'Japan'

countries.iloc[2] #The 3rd row of the dataframe.
# Values1    7.542
# Values2    3.000
# Name: Japan, dtype: float64

countries['Values1'].iloc[2] #The 3rd row of the 1st column (which is a series)
# 7.542
```

Now, if you are in fact solely dealing with a series (as your code suggests) and not a dataframe, it would look like this:

```
Country_Names = ['China', 'United States', 'Japan', 'United Kingdom', 'Russian Federation', 'Brazil']
countries = pd.Series([1.5, 10.53, 7.542, 3.487, 6.565, 8.189], index=Country_Names)
countries

# China                  1.500
# United States         10.530
# Japan                  7.542
# United Kingdom         3.487
# Russian Federation     6.565
# Brazil                 8.189
# dtype: float64

countries.index[2]
# 'Japan'

countries.iloc[2]
# 7.542
```

I'm not sure how to construct a data object that prints out like the table you have a picture of in your question, though.

**Edit**

This is how to do it. Create an index with a name and give that index to a series:

```
Country_Names = pd.Index(['China', 'United States', 'Japan', 'United Kingdom', 'Russian Federation', 'Brazil'],
                         name='Country_Names')
countries_s = pd.Series([1.5, 10.53, 7.542, 3.487, 6.565, 8.189], index=Country_Names)
countries_s

# Country_Names
# China                  1.500
# United States         10.530
# Japan                  7.542
# United Kingdom         3.487
# Russian Federation     6.565
# Brazil                 8.189
# dtype: float64
```

That pretty much confirms that you are working with a series. I'm not sure it's possible to have a dataframe with unnamed columns anyway.

Answer (score -1):

countries['Country_Name'].iloc[2]